Populate week start and week end dates basis consecutive weeks in the data



Employee
Week End Date
Derived Start Week End Date
Derived End Week End Date




John
2/3/2024
2/3/2024
2/17/2024


John
2/10/2024
2/3/2024
2/17/2024


John
2/17/2024
2/3/2024
2/17/2024


John
3/2/2024
3/2/2024
3/16/2024


John
3/9/2024
3/2/2024
3/16/2024


John
3/16/2024
3/2/2024
3/16/2024



From the above table, I need to derive using SQL the:

Derived Start Week End Date
Derived End Week End Date

For any particular employee, need to check their week end dates for the consecutives weeks, then accordingly club them together by populating Derived Start Week End Date and Derived End Week End Date.
First 3 rows are clubbed together since week end dates are consecutive and then there is a gap of more than 1 week. Therefore, last 3 rows are grouped together. When rows are clubbed, min week end date becomes Derived Start Week End Date and max week end date becomes Derived End Week End Date.
I've tried windowing functions.

Seems like a SQL gaps and islands problem

What does clubbed together mean? Please show us your window function attempt.

Using suggestions from Numbering islands in SQL Server 2012  I was able to add a group number to your clubbed together weeks.
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    Employee    VARCHAR(512),
    WeekEndDate Date
);

INSERT INTO Example (Employee, WeekEndDate) VALUES
    ('John', '2/3/2024'),
    ('John', '2/10/2024'),
    ('John', '2/17/2024'),
    ('John', '3/2/2024'),
    ('John', '3/9/2024'),
    ('John', '3/16/2024');

WITH WeeksSincePreviousCalc AS
(
Select Employee, 
       WeekEndDate, 
       DATEDIFF ( week , LAG(WeekEndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY WeekEndDate  ), WeekEndDate)  as WeeksSincePrevious
FROM Example
),
WeekGrouping as
(
select t.*,
       sum(case WeeksSincePrevious when 1
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by Employee, WeekEndDate) as grp
from  WeeksSincePreviousCalc t
),
DerivedStartEndDates as
(  
Select Employee, grp, Min(WeekEndDate) as DerivedStartWeekEndDate , Max(WeekEndDate) as DerivedEndWeekEndDate
FROM WeekGrouping
GROUP BY Employee,grp
)
Select w.Employee, w.WeekEndDate, DerivedStartWeekEndDate, DerivedEndWeekEndDate
FROM WeekGrouping   w
INNER JOIN
  DerivedStartEndDates d on d.Employee=w.employee AND  d.grp=w.grp

fiddle
cte fiddle



Employee
WeekEndDate
DerivedStartWeekEndDate
DerivedEndWeekEndDate




John
2024-02-03
2024-02-03
2024-02-17


John
2024-02-10
2024-02-03
2024-02-17


John
2024-02-17
2024-02-03
2024-02-17


John
2024-03-02
2024-03-02
2024-03-16


John
2024-03-09
2024-03-02
2024-03-16


John
2024-03-16
2024-03-02
2024-03-16



